# Is there any SQL designer (for linux or web-based) for mysql/sqlite/postgresql?

Tags: database, user-interface, database-design

I don't know if the term *SQL designer* is correct, I'm looking for a graphic tool where you can do something like:

[BOH http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/732/designerqsw.jpg](http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/732/designerqsw.jpg)

then it can generate the SQL code for the creation of the tables. Any hint?

Comment: Your image is from http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/?keyword=default.
Isn't that application good enough for your needs?

Comment: It's called an entity-relationship model, if you didn't know.

Comment: @Stan: cool! does it work only in mysql? :(
@wds: I know the ER model, I was not sure of the name of application like this. It's like I was asking for Word and you tell me "it is called document".

Comment: GenMyModel (https://www.genmymodel.com) can do that online (linux friendly, pure HTML5, no flash) with personalizable SQL generators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about [DBDesigner 4](http://fabforce.net/dbdesigner4/index.php). It runs under Linux & Windows and is licensed under the GPL.

[image]
<sub>(source: [fabforce.net](http://fabforce.net/dbdesigner4/images/screenshots.jpg))</sub>

Comment: great, I'm gonna trying it, thank you!

Comment: I'd never heard of this product, I'll have to make a note to try it out at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I think that DBDesigner don't draw links precisely between the rows in relation, as the bad "SQL Designer" do !

I'm also looking for this kind of tool, but without the bugs who squat SQL Designer.